# Solve $\sqrt3 \cot^2 x - 2 \cot x - \sqrt3 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I thought it'd be nice to factor this as follows: $\sqrt3 \cot^2 x - 2 \cot x - \sqrt3 = 0 $, so: $(\sqrt3 \cot x + 1)(\cot x - \sqrt3) = 0$.

So there are 2 equations to solve:

1. $\sqrt3 \cot x + 1 = 0$. I thought to multiply both sides by $\tan
       x$, yielding: $\sqrt3 + \tan x = 0$. Hence: $\tan x = -\sqrt3$ and
   $x = \{ -\frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi \}$
2. $\cot x - \sqrt3 = 0$, so $\cot x - \sqrt3 = 0$, $\cot x = \sqrt3$.
   Multiplying by $\tan x$ yields: $1 = \sqrt3 \tan x$, dividing both
   sides by $\sqrt3$: $\frac{\sqrt3}{3} = \tan x$, so $x = \{
   \frac{\pi}{6} + k\pi\}$

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Yes, except $\arctan(-\sqrt{3})=-\frac{\pi}{3}$. Perhaps that was a typo?

Comment: Also: when you multiply by $\tan x$, you might be multiplying by $0$ (if $\sin x = 0$). So in the next line, you should write $x \ne \ldots, -\pi, 0, \pi, \ldots$ next to the equation you get. Consider as an example of what can go wrong the equation $$\sin x \cot x = 0.$$ Multiply through by $\tan x$ to get $\sin x = 0$. Solve to get $x = 0, \pm \pi, \ldots$...which is wrong, because $\sin x \cot x$ isn't even defined for those $x$-values.

Comment: Following the observation of @JohnHughes, before you multiply by $\tan x$ you could simply add "since we know that $\tan x\ne0$ we can multiply both sides by $\tan x\cdots$ Also, you still have not corrected your erroneous $-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales that was a typo indeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\tan x\neq 0$, multiplying throughout by $\tan^2x$, moving terms to RHS, and putting $t=\tan x$ gives

$$\sqrt3\ t^2+2t-\sqrt3=0\\
(\sqrt3\ t-1)(t+\sqrt3)=0\\
t=\tan x=\frac 1{\sqrt3}, -\sqrt3\\
x=n\pi+\frac {\pi}6, n\pi-\frac {\pi}3$$

Comment: Note that if $\tan x=0$ then $\cot x$ is undefined so there is no need to **assume** that $\tan x\ne0$ for this particular exercise.